# Добавить авторизацию

Tags: html, css, frontend

я только недавно начал учить html и css, помогите пожалуйста поставить регистрацию на сайт, чтобы на него можно было зайти только с определенным паролем.

Comment: Видно что ты только начал изучать.... Ты что-нибудь слышал о такой вещи как сервер?

Comment: мне нужно чтобы он работал без интернета, у нас завтра конкурс. я а все еще не могу понять как защиту поставить

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: я бы сам рад понять...

Comment: а как обеспечивается "мне нужно чтобы он работал без интернета" и "регистрацию на сайт, чтобы на него можно было зайти"? - как заходить на сайт без интернета? Это какая-то локальная сеть?

Comment: чтобы зайти с самого html файла на пк который находится

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Самое простое:

```js
let enterPassword = '1';

while (true) {
    let pass = prompt('Введите пароль!');
    
    if (pass === enterPassword) {
        alert('Добро пожаловать!');
        break;
    }
}
```

Перед запуском цикла, можно поставить модальное окно, чтобы ничего не было видно, а после успешного входа - убрать модалку

Comment: спасибо, но как его соединить с мои html кодом, чтобы не показывало страницу пока не напишеш пароль?

Comment: Извините, но я не вижу ваш html. Наверное интернет лагает и я не могу попасть на ваш компьютер и монитор

Comment: Как сделать - написано под кодом в моём ответе

Comment: Заработало, спасибо большое

Comment: Если ответ помог - галочку рядом с ответом тык! %)

Answer (score 0):

В настоящих веб сайтах для регистрации и входа в аккаунт используют язык программирования на стороне сервера (PHP, node js, python, java).

С помощью HTML и CSS реализовать такое не возможно. Можно только создать форму для регистрации, поле для ввода пароля и логина, но работать не будет.
[Вот пример реализации регистрации на PHP](https://ruseller.com/lessons.php?id=347&rub=37)
Но без базовых знаний PHP/MySQL ты даже скопировать его не сможешь.

Имей ввиду что для того чтобы зарабатывать на веб разработке не обязательно уметь писать код для сервера (backend). Если ты хочешь стать Frontend разработчиком тебе не обязательно учить backend.